# Different approach with one-to-one relationship

Tags: sql, one-to-one

I am trying to find out what are the differences when implementing one-to-one relationship. What is the difference between scenario 1 and 2? Why would you choose 1 over 2, and vice-versa? Does each approach have a name?

**Scenario 1**:

User

```
Id     Name
100    John
```

UserBalance

```
Id     Balance
100    3.00
```

**Scenario 2**:

User

```
Id     Name  UserBalance_Id
100    John  50
```

UserBalance

```
Id     Balance
50     3.00
```

Comment: There is really no point in scenario 2 because you'll end up with a table with every possible balance in it from 0 to a zillion.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I read it that he is not normalizing the amount (since he specifically considered it a 1-1 join), but just 1 row per user.

Comment: Yes you're right. That makes scenario 2 even less attractive

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid balance is just an example. it could be anything.

Comment: If it's anything then this is just a question about vertical partitioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scenario 1 would be the more common approach in my experience, it allows you to access the balance directly with the same unique key as accessing the user - that direct access can give you performance benefits.

Scenario 2 does not give you that benefit, and introduces a further arbitrary ID, preventing that direct access and using more storage / memory.

Comment: O k, memory is one pro for scenario 1, Could it be that if UserBalance had its own key, it would be possible/easier to create relationships when introducting third table that could have relationship with UserBalance?

Comment: No easier than using the shared unique id of the user in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I think **Scenario 1** better because you are saving memory for an unnecessary column. Which you are using in **Scenario 2** as `UserBalance_Id`.